# Merging two dataframes within a loop

Tags: r, merge

I have one big dataframe that needs to be populated within a loop, where, at each step, data for a different year are imported.

Let's say the big dataframe `df1` is initialized like this:

```
date VAR 
2006-01-01 NA 
2006-01-02 NA 
2006-01-03 NA 
...
2007-01-01 NA 
2007-01-02 NA 
...
2008-01-01 NA 
2008-01-02 NA
```

At each step of the loop (i.e., a different year) I have such data `df2`:

```
date VAR
2006-01-01 NA
2006-01-02 NA
...
```

How could I "populate" `df1` by values in `df2`, using some basic R functions, e.g. `merge`? I would also like to keep `NA` where data from `df2` are missing. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Partially, the use of `df1 <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)` seems to work properly, but new rows are added instead of merging with the existing ones

Comment: It seems unlikely that the behaviour you are looking for isn't covered by one of the many joins (left, right, inner, outer, semi, anti, cross, rolling). But if it truly isn't please post a question with [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and expected output so we can see what it is you are trying to do.